# Would like to generate or spool a HTML file based on a condition

Tags: html, sql, spool

Would like to generate or spool a HTML file based on a condition for instance in the below case where only if the result count is greater that 0 spool the html file or else don't

```
DECLARE 

VAL1 INT;

BEGIN

select count(*) into VAL1 from <tablename> where dbkey in (<key>);

IF VAL1 = 1 THEN

SET MARKUP HTML ON SPOOL ON PREFORMAT OFF ENTMAP ON -
HEAD "<TITLE>Document Title</TITLE> -
<STYLE type='text/css'> -
</STYLE>" -
BODY "TEXT='#000000'" -
TABLE "WIDTH='50%' BORDER='1'"

SPOOL D:\duplicate.html

COLUMN NAME HEADING 'columnName'
COLUMN SNAME HEADING 'columnName'
COLUMN DEPARTMENT HEADING 'columnName'

select <NAME>,<columnName>,<SNAME> from <tablename> where dbkey in (<key>);

SPOOL OFF

ELSE

END

END IF;

END;
```